# Trebuchet: Disable/Hide Dock

Tags: cyanogenmod, launcher, trebuchet

Is there a way to disable the dock entirely on Trebuchet on CyanogenMod?  I find that I always go to my main home screen before touching the app drawer out of habit, so I'd like to have that extra space for the regular screens.  Is this possible?

Comment: Off-topic, when you say "out of habit", is it because you used a different launcher before that had this behavior? If yes, what launcher was it?

Comment: @geffchang No, I just have an apparently irrevocable reflex to go to my main home screen before launching something from the dock :-/

Answer (score 3):

There does not seem to be a way to do that in Trebuchet on CyanogenMod (when not on CyanogenMod you can do it in the Trebuchet Settings).

As an alternative you could use nova launcher, it is free and the dock is removeable (even on CyanogenMod).

There may be many more launcher providing this feature, but nova is tho only one I used on CyanogenMod.

Comment: Nova launcher isn't in f-droid :/